# FBSession, checking if logged in?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

I have implemented the facebook login into my app however right now I've been playing around with the login/logout states and what a modal view to pop only if the user is logged out...anyways this is what I have and its not working?

```
 if (FBSessionStateClosed) {
     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"TestModal" sender:nil];
 }
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: At the point where you expect the user to be logged out, can you log the output of `[FBSession activeSession] state]` and see what state it's in?

Answer (score 0):

If I get u correctly, your session should be still Open.
Double check did you perform this line when user logout?

```
[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Use Following method may be help you :

```
-(void)openFacebookAuthentication
{
    NSArray *permission = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:kFBEmailPermission,kFBUserPhotosPermission, nil];

    FBSession *session = [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:permission];

    [FBSession setActiveSession: [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:permission] ];

    [[FBSession activeSession] openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {

        switch (status) {
            case FBSessionStateOpen:
                [self getMyData];
                break;
            case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed: {
                // prefer to keep decls near to their use
                // unpack the error code and reason in order to compute cancel bool
                NSString *errorCode = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:FBErrorLoginFailedOriginalErrorCode];
                NSString *errorReason = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:FBErrorLoginFailedReason];
                BOOL userDidCancel = !errorCode && (!errorReason || [errorReason isEqualToString:FBErrorLoginFailedReasonInlineCancelledValue]);


                if(error.code == 2 && ![errorReason isEqualToString:kFBSdkUserLoginFail]) {
                    UIAlertView *errorMessage = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:kFBAlertTitle
                                                                           message:kFBAuthenticationErrorMessage
                                                                           delegate:nil
                                                                           cancelButtonTitle:kOk
                                                                           otherButtonTitles:nil];
                    [errorMessage performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
                    errorMessage = nil;
                    }
                }
                break;
                // presently extension, log-out and invalidation are being implemented in the Facebook class
            default:
                break; // so we do nothing in response to those state transitions
        }
    }];
    permission = nil;
}
```